# Why notebook does not work in julia on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, julia, ijulia-notebook

I have installed julia (on ubuntu 20.04) and want to run it in notebook. For this I used:

```
Pkg.add("IJulia")
using IJulia
notebook()
```

But in the end it opens this:

```
[ Info: running `/usr/bin/snap notebook`
Process(setenv(`/usr/bin/snap notebook`; dir="/home/myname"), ProcessExited(64))
```

But the browser with the notebook does not open, as promised in the tutorials. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason it's running the `snap` command instead of running Jupyter. (1) Can you run `Pkg.build("IJulia")` in the Julia REPL and then try `notebook()` again? (2) check if the JUPYTER env variable is set to `snap` for some reason (`print(ENV["JUPYTER"])` in the Julia REPL).